# How to label below and above arrows in TikZ Automata?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

Using the `automata` package I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial] (p) {p};
        \node[state,accepting, right of=p] (q) {q};
        \draw (q) edge[loop above] node{a}  (q);
        \draw (p) edge[above] node{b} (q);
        % \draw (p) edge[below] node{c} (q);
        
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

However, I would like to add a label `c` below arrow `b`. How to do this?

Comment: `\path (p) edge node[above] {b} node[below] {c} (q);` should do it.

Comment: Yes, it does it! But what is the difference between edge[above] and edge node[above] ? From where can I read more about this?

Comment: `edge[above]` makes all following nodes use `above` (i.e. `anchor=south`), though it should be possible to do `edge[above] node{b} node[below]{c}`.

Answer (score 1):

- in on arrow can be placed several nose.With their option(s) can be set above or below arrow, or on any other position on arrow,
- labels on arrows you can write with help of `quotes` library
- option `auto` positioned labels on arrows depending on arrow direction. See @Qrrbrbirlbel comment below()thank you for pointing this)

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
                quotes}
                
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 22mm,
            > = Stealth
                    ]
    \node[state, initial] (p) {p};
    \node[state,accepting, right of=p] (q) {q};
    %
    \draw[->] (q) edge[loop above] node{a}  (q);
    \draw[->] (p) edge node[above] {b} node[below] {c} (q);
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 22mm,
            > = Stealth
                    ]
    \node[state, initial] (p) {p};
    \node[state,accepting, right of=p] (q) {q};

    \draw[->] (q) edge[loop above, "a"] (q);
    \draw[->] (p) edge["b", "c" '] (q);     % or "swap" instead of '
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify things: [`auto`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/auto) makes it so that the nodes on edges automatically use the appropriate `above`, `above left`, `left`, etc. depending on the direction of the connection. `swap` (shortcut: `'`) swaps the side of `auto`. The `quotes` library just implements the `"text"` syntax.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, you are right. I should this mentioned in answer ...